# What is a tractable calculus of Integral of $\exp(a x^n +b)$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

What is the anti-derivative in $x$ of $$f(x)=\exp(a x^n +b)$$ with $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $n>0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Given your profile, I assume this isn't homework. Unfortunately there is no closed formula for _integer_ $n > 1$, and matters do not improve for non-integer $n$. Particularly, the exponential expression $x^n$ is problematic if $x < 0$ and $n$ is not an integer.

Comment: For a positive $a$ and $n>1$, the anti-derivative is: $$-x e^b  \frac{E_{(n - 1)/n}(-a x^n)}{n} + constant$$ with $E_a(x)$ being the Exponential Integral function. I should precise $n>0$...

Comment: if you already know the answer, what is the question?

Comment: Of course, this is essentially just the definition of $E_a(x)$.

Comment: because in my comment i assume $a$ to be positive while in my question, it may be a negative real.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\exp(ax^n+b)\,dx$$
take the $b$ outside the integral as it is just a constant, and let $u=a^{1/n}x\Rightarrow dx=a^{-1/n}u$ and you are left with:
$$I=a^{-1/n}e^b\int\exp(u^n)\,du$$
now with another simple substitution you should see it looks a lot like the Exponential integral

Comment: Many thanks, i should have thought your answer before posting.